# Application installation failed from iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I changed the version number to a higher version in my iPhone app. When I run the application from XCode, it runs successfully. But When I try putting it on my device from iTunes, installation failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the crash / error code?

Comment: I get popup on device "Application failed to install".

Comment: did you check that your provision includes the device you try to install on ?

Comment: I am running the application on device from xcode with same profile. Its running fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten this error before.  It happened because I signed the build and the IPA with different keys by mistake.  You need to be sure the one in your build settings matches the one you use to sign the IPA when you make it from the archive.  Also of course they both need to be adhoc certificates,

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the Profile that is present In settings>General>profiles there delete the profile that belongs to your app also delete the app from the iPhone and download a profile form developer.apple yourAccount then drag and drop on the desktop and double click it and then drag and drop both ipa nad that profile in to the iTunes then sync the app will install now